# Using react-multi-carousel but unable to use custom dots

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-multi-carousel

How I can get clickable custom dots of this carousel.
I cannot bind a click event in the list item to move the carousel. I need a proper implementation between `onClick` and the `li` item to click on prev and next items in carousel

Here is the full code in the link [codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-wind-giqk7?file=/src/App.js)

```js
const CustomDot = ({onMove,index,onClick,active}) => {   
   return (
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#main-slide" data-slide-to="0" className={active ? "active" : "inactive"}     
      >How t bind the click event list item
  onClick={() => onClick()}>{React.Children.slide1}</li>
    <li data-target="#main-slide" data-slide-to="1" className={active ? "active" : "inactive"}
  onClick={() => onClick()}>{React.Children.slide2} </li>
    <li data-target="#main-slide" data-slide-to="2" className={active ? "active" : "inactive"}
  onClick={() => onClick()}>{React.Children.slide3} </li>
    </ol>
  );
};
```

Comment: which Carousel plugin are you using? Can you show the code of the carousel itself? Or event better, create a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-wind-giqk7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the plugin expects to receive a [single element](https://github.com/YIZHUANG/react-multi-carousel/blob/6383098c56a7944487380194cdacdcfcd0219944/stories/CustomDot.js#L6) (`li` for example) as `CusomtDot` but you pass a list (`ol` with some children).

The solution, pass a single element, like this:

```js
const CustomDot = ({ onMove, index, onClick, active }) => {
  // onMove means if dragging or swiping in progress.
  // active is provided by this lib for checking if the item is active or not.
  return (
    <li
      className={active ? "active" : "inactive"}
      onClick={() => onClick()}
    >
      {index + 1}
    </li>
  );
};
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-carousel-customdot-jwkfo

Comment: can you also add aclick event follow up if we want to customise the arrows

Comment: They've a good example here - https://github.com/YIZHUANG/react-multi-carousel/blob/master/stories/CustomArrows.js. Let me know if more explanations needed.

Comment: Yeah they have but the implementation still doesn't sets well. I used it's CustomLeftArrow and CustomRightArrow but it didn't worked out.

Comment: Want to share a codesandbox again ? so I could try to point to the problematic parts

Comment: @MoshFeu I get the error: "Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ onMove: any; index: any; onClick: any; active: any; }" What can i do

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox that shows the error for me? It would be easier for me to investigate..

Answer (score 3):

```
const CustomDot = ({ onMove, index, onClick, active }) => {
  return (
    <li
      className={active ? "active" : "inactive"}
      onClick={() => onClick()}
    >
      <MaximizeIcon />
    </li>
  );
};

const arrowStyle = {
  background: "transparent",
  border: 0,
  color: "#fff",
  fontSize: "80px"
};
const CustomRight = ({ onClick }) => (
  <button className="arrow right" onClick={onClick} style={arrowStyle}>
    <ArrowForwardIcon style={{ fontSize: "50px" }} />
  </button>
);
const CustomLeft = ({ onClick }) => (
  <button className="arrow left" onClick={onClick} style={arrowStyle}>
    <ArrowBackIcon style={{ fontSize: "50px" }} />
  </button>
);
```

Working demo :  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-carousel-customdot-3q0f4?file=/src/App.js:683-1052

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of active through tailwind

```
 const CustomDot = ({ onMove, index, onClick, active }: any) => {
    return (
      <li
        className={active ? "text-red-500" : "inactive"}
        onClick={() => onClick()}
      >
        {index + 1}
      </li>
    );
  };
```